# A sequence of sets that decreases to $\emptyset$ but each element has positive outer measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This problem is from *Measure Theory* by *Donald Cohn*. *Section 1.4, problem 7*.

Show that there exists a decreasing sequence $\{A_n\}$ of subsets of $[0,1]$ such that $λ^*(A_n) = 1$ holds for each $n$, but for which $\bigcap_nAn = ∅$ ($\lambda^*$ is the *Lebesgue outer measure* on $\mathbb{R}$).

(Hint: Let $B$ be a Hamel basis for $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $\{B_n\}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of sets such that $B = \bigcup_n B_n$. For each $n$ let $V_n$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ spanned by $B_n$, and let $A_n = [0,1]\cap V^c_n$.)

I have shown that  each
*Lebesgue subset* of $V_n$ has Lebesgue measure zero but could not show the rest.

Please help.

Comment: Note  that `$\emptyset$` produces $\emptyset$.